# How to use "longClickGesture" in appium UiAutomator2 with x and y coordinates?

Tags: selenium, automation, appium, android-testing, android-uiautomator

I'm fairly new to Appium, and trying to understand mobile gestures using UIautomator2 . The official documentation provides JAVA syntax on how to use the "longClickGesture" when element id is present.

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("mobile: longClickGesture", ImmutableMap.of(
    "elementId", ((RemoteWebElement) element).getId()
));
```

Can someone tell me how to use the above syntax when element id is absent and only with x and y coordinates.

I tried searching in different forums but could not see any direct answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
.swipe(x, y, x, y, 300)


# ruby
swipe start_x: 75, start_y: 500, end_x: 75, end_y: 500, duration: 0.8 
# python 
driver.swipe(start_x=75, start_y=500, end_x=75, end_y=500, duration=800) 
// java 
driver.swipe(75, 500, 75, 500, 0.8)
```

And give the same position for x and y
This will be the same as long click.